# Spree administration AJAX request works in development, 404s in production

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nginx, passenger, spree

I'm building a site on Spree 0.70.3 and Rails 3.1.3. In development I just run thin on port 3000; in production, we have Passenger 3.0.9 and Nginx 1.0.8.

When associating a Product with a Taxon in Spree, you come to a page with an empty list of taxons. Starting to type in a Search box triggers an AJAX post request to find taxons matching that string and display them as potential taxons for the product.

In development, this works fine; I can see the requests coming in the development log, and taxons appear on the page. In production, the Chrome console shows that the AJAX request is getting a 404 response. The Nginx logs simply record the 404 response; the Rails logs show no record of the request. My guess is that Nginx is seeing that the request has a `.js` file extension and is looking for a file, perhaps in the `public/` directory, rather than sending the request to Rails.

Has anyone encountered this problem with Spree/Nginx before? How can I get Nginx to log more data about how it's trying to resolve the request? Is there anything about the Nginx configuration I should be checking here?

ETA: I've ramped up Nginx logging, and it definitely looks as though Nginx is looking for the `.js` file as an actual file rather than handing the request on to Passenger and Rails. Can this be configured?

```
2012/01/27 14:33:17 [error] 4430#0: *2 open() "/var/www/live/current/public/admin/products/<product_slug>/taxons/available.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 64.134.40.51, server: <obfuscated>.com, request: "POST /admin/products/<product_slug>/taxons/available.js HTTP/1.1", host: "<obfuscated>", referrer: "https://<obfuscated>/admin/products/<product_slug>/taxons/selected"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turns out to be Nginx/Passenger. I found [this mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/group/phusion-passenger/browse_thread/thread/2aaccc53d5bb5dab/650b002099539d92?lnk=gst) which indicated that any `location` blocks within the Nginx configuration need their own `passenger_enabled on;` directives. So this block

```
# "Far-future" expiration dates
location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ {
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        expires                        max;
        break;
    }
}
```

needed to look like this

```
# "Far-future" expiration dates
location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ {
    passenger_enabled on;
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        expires                        max;
        break;
    }
}
```

That resolved the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem. What should I do if I have Nginx/Unicorn?

Comment: @zolter I would post a new question about that; my solution is Passenger-specific. I'm not familiar enough with how Nginx and Unicorn interface to speculate on whether this solution would carry over.